# a theorem in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

There is a theorem in a logic book that depicts that for every formula $A$, there exists a formula $B$ in $\mathcal L $such that $ \vDash A\leftrightarrow B $ and $ FV(B) \cap BV(B) = \emptyset %$

Here are some lemmas that might help.

$\bullet$ Assume $\mathcal L$ is a language and $\mathcal M$ is a $\mathcal L$-Structure, $\mathcal t$ be a term and $A$ a formula in $\mathcal L$ and $a \in M$, M the universe of the language.

Now if $z \notin FV(t)$, then $t[x|\overline a] = (t[x|z])[z|\overline a]$.

and if $z \notin FV(A)$ and $z$ is free for $x$ in $A$ then $A[x|\overline a] = (A[x|z])[z|\overline a]$.

$\bullet \vDash \forall xA[z|x] \leftrightarrow \forall y A[z|y]$

$\bullet \vDash \exists x A[z|x] \leftrightarrow  \exists y A[z|y]$

With these lemmas, the question could be solved.

However, I can not understand how such B exists. I would appreciate it if someone would help me.

Comment: Not very clear... IMO, it means that we can rename bound variables and the result is a new formula equivalent to the initial one. Example: $\forall x Px \equiv \forall z Pz$.

Comment: Thus, if $A$ is $\forall x Px \to Qx$ we have that e.g. $\forall x Px \to Qy$ is not equivalent to $A$, but we can rename the bound variable in the first formula to get the equivalent $\forall z Pz \to Qx$, which is the $B$.

Comment: Due to the fact that the number of variables of the language is infinite while a formula is a finite expression, we can always find a new variable $z$ not occurring at all in the formula and use it in such a way that $z \notin FV(B) \cap BV(B)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If by $\forall x. P x \to Q x$ you mean $(\forall x. P x) \to Q x$, then I agree with you. Otherwise, if the $x$ in $Qx$ is bound, then the formula $B$ that you present is still not equivalent to $A$, right?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your comments.